# Is there a faster way of adding up time ranges, taking overlaps into account?

Tags: sql-server

I have a subquery that is taking multiple minutes to execute. If I pull out just the initial rows that are being added up, it only takes half a second with 2,400ish rows so I don't understand why the main query doing the sum is taking so long.

What I'm trying to do is for all the transactions in a date range, for all the workers assigned to those transactions, add up the scheduled hours for each worker.

The query is returning the correct data, it's just taking FOREVER to do it.

**QUERY**

```
 SELECT scheduled_hours = COALESCE(sum(hours), 0), worker_sysid
            FROM (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                    B.DateR1,
                    B.DateR2,
                    hours = ABS((B.DAteR1 - B.DateR2) / 3600),
                    B.worker_sysid
                 FROM Trans A
                OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT 
                           DateR1 = MIN(TRANS_START),
                           DateR2 = MAX(TRANS_END),
                           worker_sysid
                    FROM Trans
                    JOIN trans_workers ON trans_workers.trans_sysid = Trans.SYSID
                    LEFT JOIN Service ON Service.SYSID = Trans.SERVICESYSID
                    WHERE
                        TRANS_START <= A.TRANS_END AND TRANS_END >= A.TRANS_START
                        AND TRANS_START IS NOT NULL AND TRANS_END IS NOT NULL
                        AND TRANS_START != '' AND TRANS_END != ''
                        AND Trans.CHARGEBY IN ('Hours', 'Hour')
                        AND (
                            COALESCE(Service.overnight, 0) != 1
                            OR
                            COALESCE(Service.active_overnight, 0) = 1
                        )
                        AND TRANSDATE BETWEEN 80387 AND 80400 ### These are Clarion dates
                        AND trans_workers.deleted_at IS NULL
                        GROUP BY worker_sysid
                ) B
            ) A
            WHERE worker_sysid IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY worker_sysid
```

TABLES

**Trans**: SYSID (int, pk), TRANSDATE (int, clarion-formatted date), TRANS_START / TRANS_END (UNIX timestamp), SERVICESYSID (int, fk), CHARGEBY (varchar)

**trans_workers**: trans_sysid, worker_sysid, deleted_at

**Service**: SYSID (int, pk)

**UPDATE**

Moving the trans_workers join out of the OUTER APPLY has reduced the execution time from 1 minute down to 16 seconds, so that's an improvement.

```
SELECT scheduled_hours = COALESCE(sum(hours), 0), worker_sysid
            FROM (
                 SELECT DISTINCT
                    B.DateR1,
                    B.DateR2,
                    hours = ABS((B.DateR1 - B.DateR2) / 3600),
                    worker_sysid
                 FROM Trans A
                 JOIN trans_workers ON A.SYSID = trans_workers.trans_sysid
                OUTER APPLY (
                    SELECT 
                           DateR1 = MIN(TRANS_START),
                           DateR2 = MAX(TRANS_END),
                           Trans.SYSID
                    FROM Trans
                    LEFT JOIN Service ON Service.SYSID = Trans.SERVICESYSID
                    WHERE
                        TRANS_START <= A.TRANS_END AND TRANS_END >= A.TRANS_START
                        AND TRANS_START IS NOT NULL AND TRANS_END IS NOT NULL
                        AND TRANS_START != '' AND TRANS_END != ''
                        AND Trans.CHARGEBY IN ('Hours', 'Hour')
                        AND COALESCE(Service.overnight, 0) != 1
                        AND TRANSDATE BETWEEN 80387 AND 80400
                        GROUP BY Trans.SYSID
                ) B
            ) A
            WHERE worker_sysid IS NOT NULL
            GROUP BY worker_sysid
            ORDER BY worker_sysid
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/consolidate-overlapping-date-periods I have a query that executes in under a second and returns what appear to be the correct hours. Only problem being I don't understand what's happening.

```
DECLARE @start INTEGER, @end INTEGER;
SET @start = 80401; --06/02/2021
SET @end = 80414; --19/02/2021

WITH cteTemp
AS (
    SELECT
        worker_sysid,
        BeginDate =
            CASE
                WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_sysid ORDER BY theDate) - openCnt = 0 THEN theDate
            END,
        EndDate =
            CASE
            WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_sysid ORDER BY theDate) - closeCnt = 0 THEN theDate
            END
    FROM (
        SELECT
            worker_sysid,
            theDate = DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, (dateadd(day,[TRANSDATE]-(4),'1801-01-01')))) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(second, TRANS_START - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01')), DATEADD(second, TRANS_START - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01')),
            closeCnt = NULL,
            openCnt = (ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_sysid ORDER BY DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, (dateadd(day,[TRANSDATE]-(4),'1801-01-01')))) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(second, TRANS_START - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01')), DATEADD(second, TRANS_START - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01'))) * 2) - 1
        FROM 
            Trans
        INNER JOIN trans_workers ON trans_workers.trans_sysid = Trans.SYSID
        JOIN Service ON Service.SYSID = Trans.SERVICESYSID
        WHERE 
            worker_sysid IS NOT NULL
            AND Trans.deleted_at IS NULL
            AND trans_workers.deleted_at IS NULL
            AND Trans.CHARGEBY IN ('Hour', 'Hours')
            AND (transCancelled IS NULL OR transCancelled != 1)
            AND (
                COALESCE(Service.overnight, 0) = 0
            )
            AND TRANSDATE BETWEEN @start AND @end
        UNION ALL

        SELECT
            worker_sysid,
            theDate = DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, (dateadd(day,[TRANSDATE]-(4),'1801-01-01')))) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(second, TRANS_END - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01')), DATEADD(second, TRANS_END - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01')),
            closeCnt = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_sysid ORDER BY worker_sysid, DATEADD(day, 0, DATEDIFF(day, 0, (dateadd(day,[TRANSDATE]-(4),'1801-01-01')))) + DATEADD(day, 0 - DATEDIFF(day, 0, DATEADD(second, TRANS_END - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01')), DATEADD(second, TRANS_END - DATEDIFF(S, GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()), '1970-01-01'))) * 2,
            openCnt = NULL            
        FROM
            Trans
        JOIN trans_workers ON trans_workers.trans_sysid = Trans.SYSID
        JOIN Service ON Service.SYSID = Trans.SERVICESYSID
        WHERE 
            worker_sysid IS NOT NULL
            AND Trans.deleted_at IS NULL
            AND trans_workers.deleted_at IS NULL
            AND Trans.CHARGEBY IN ('Hour', 'Hours')
            AND (transCancelled IS NULL OR transCancelled != 1)
            AND (
                COALESCE(Service.overnight, 0) = 0
                
            )
            AND TRANSDATE BETWEEN @start AND @end
        )
    AS baseSelected
)

SELECT scheduled_hours = SUM(hours), worker_sysid 
FROM (
    SELECT
        dt.worker_sysid,
        hours = CAST(ABS(DATEDIFF(second, MIN(dt.BeginDate), MAX(dt.EndDate))) / 3600.0 AS DECIMAL(10,2))
    FROM (
        SELECT
            worker_sysid,
            BeginDate,
            EndDate,
            grpID =
            IIF(BeginDate IS NOT NULL, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_sysid ORDER BY worker_sysid, BeginDate), ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY worker_sysid ORDER BY worker_sysid, EndDate))
        FROM
            cteTemp
        WHERE 
            BeginDate IS NOT NULL OR EndDate IS NOT NULL
    )
    AS dt 
    GROUP BY dt.worker_sysid,grpID
) AS final_table
GROUP BY worker_sysid ORDER BY worker_sysid
```

Bonus points to myself for conversions because the DATE of each transaction is in Clarion and the TIME of each transaction is a Unix timestamp